# Prove that T: ℝ2->ℝ2; T(a1,b1)=(a1,a1) is not a linear transform.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I already checked that it satisfies both axioms T(a+b)=T(a)+T(b) and T(αa)=αT(a), so I'm a bit confused... Isn't it true that it must satisfy this two axioms in order to be a linear transform? How do I prove that it is NOT? Could anyone give me a hint? Thank you!

Comment: Easiest way is proof by contradiction. Assume that the criterion holds for some points and start to work it out until you come to an inconsistency.

Comment: @anderstood, T is linear, not bilinear.

Comment: The transformation $T$, as you wrote it, is in fact a linear transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear transformation.

$$T((a_1,b_1) + (a_2,b_2)) = T(a_1+a_2,a_2+b_2) = (a_1+a_2,a_1+a_2) = (a_1,a_1) + (a_2, a_2) = T(a_1,b_1) + T(a_2, b_2)$$
and
$$T(\alpha(a_1,b_1)) = T(\alpha a_1, \alpha b_1) = (\alpha a_1, \alpha a_1) = \alpha (a_1, a_1) = \alpha T(a_1, b_1)$$

Are you sure you wrote the question down correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can check that $T$ is a linear transformation either by checking the axioms as user275673 did, or by (if one knows the correspondence between linear maps and matrices) noting that 
$$
T(a,b)=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\,\begin{bmatrix}a\\ b\end{bmatrix}. 
$$